# Any pitfalls in switching from MRI to JRuby?

Tags: ruby, windows, jruby, sikuli

I want to use SikuliX and seems like it would need JRuby. Having them both with MinGW Ruby on the same machine could be painfull, since pik has a bunch of Issues on GitHub and is getting old.

So I'm thinking about total switch to JRuby. But what would I lose? What problems I would encounter?

**UPD:** is there any list of unsupported gems for example?

Comment: Any gems that build natively in C will be incompatible. There is an experimental - and now deprecated - system to make them work, but I was never able to get satisfactory results with it. Gems like RMagick, database adaptors and Nokogiri will be affected. A list of alternatives is here, no idea how up-to-date: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives

Comment: You can have both Rubys installed at once without conflict. I have MRI and JRuby installed on Windows from packaged binaries, without Pik; the JRuby binaries start with `j`, so there's not much chance of them clashing with each other. If there is a risk of clashing I'm not aware of, you could always just keep only one of them in your path at a time. I assume SikuliX has its own setting for where to find JRuby, so you may be able to keep JRuby out of your path altogether.

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comment(s) C extension gems are an issue, but most (popular) gems such as Nokogiri provide a native Java extension version as well - thus should be fine there.

things such as native DB adapters do not have "direct" Java alternatives, but assuming there's another library (ORM) using them you won't have issues switching ... e.g. DM has direct support for using the Java database standard when on JRuby, for AR there's a compatibility layer esp. called ActiveRecord-JDBC-Adapter that provides compatible adapters.